# Someone plagiarized one of my answers. Now what?

Tags: discussion, licensing, legal, copyright

Recently someone commented on an answer I wrote to [Difference between 3-Tier architecture and MVC (Model, View Controller) in ASP.Net](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/299836/118878) that they believe a blog post on blog.devgenius.io (a site operated by Medium.com) was essentially copied and pasted from my answer.

- My answer written in 2015: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/299881/118878
- Blog post in question (written in 2020): [Three Tier Architecture vs MVC Architecture](https://blog.devgenius.io/three-tier-architecture-vs-mvc-architecture-1ed0d195e427)

Since my answer was written in 2015, it is covered by the [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license.

The opening paragraph of the blog post was adapted to make sense as a standalone post, but the rest of the blog post appears to be a copy-and-paste of my answer. The exception being the author used "hazy" instead of "fuzzy" in one of the subheads. Furthermore, no attribution is given at all.

I sent an e-mail to Medium.com, and they were very responsive, but replied back that I needed to issue an official DMCA takedown notice — which is fair. My e-mail was informative, but not an official takedown notice. [Medium has an online form to submit a takedown notice](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=165717&form=true), but I'm not sure if I'm authorized to do that.

Am I (the author of the answer) authorized to submit the DMCA takedown notice, and if not, who is?

Comment: We can't give you legal advice here. However, when you post content on any Stack Exchange site, you are only granting Stack Exchange a perpetual and irrevocable license to use your content, with the license dependent on when you posted or edited the content. Since you're only granting a license, you retain control on the use of your work in other ways. [Stack Exchange offers some guidance on what you can do if you find scraped content on another site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/572) If you have further questions about your legal options, you may want to consult an expert.